# Looking for a good "create" database scripting tool (not diff scripting)

Tags: msbuild, datadude, databasescripting

I'm looking for a db script tool which can do the following:

1. Create "create-scripts" for each table in the database and place them in separate files. Note: these files should not contain relational constraints.
2. Create scripts for relational constraints (as one file or many, doesn't matter)
3. Create insert scripts for populating tables.

We are going to put the scripts into tfs and they will be updated fairly often, so a tool which is fast and efficient to is highly preferred. I'm going to integrate these scripts into msbuild to create a database for our integration tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Visual Studio Database Professional. If you are using Visual Studio 2010 it is included with Ultimate (and perhaps other versions). For Visual Studio 2008 Team Developer it is a free download. It is fantastic and easy to deploy using MSBuild. All of the scripts  that you store are create scripts, broken down by type similar to what you specified in your question.